# Put a button on a page from a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-button

I'm using ViewPager. I want to put a button on each page, but in doing so fills the entire page. I would like to determine the width and height of button but do not know how.

This is my code:

Pager Activity

```
public class PagerActivity extends Activity {

PagerContainer mContainer;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContainer = (PagerContainer) findViewById(R.id.pager_container);

    ViewPager pager = mContainer.getViewPager();
    PagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    //Necessary or the pager will only have one extra page to show
    // make this at least however many pages you can see
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(adapter.getCount());
    //A little space between pages
    pager.setPageMargin(15);

    //If hardware acceleration is enabled, you should also remove
    // clipping on the pager for its children.
    pager.setClipChildren(false);




}

//Nothing special about this adapter, just throwing up colored views for demo
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TextView view = new TextView(PagerActivity.this);
        view.setText("Item "+position);
        view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, position * 50, position * 10, position * 50));
        view.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CA2C68"));

        Button buttonView = new Button(PagerActivity.this);
        buttonView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_states_azul);


        container.addView(buttonView);
        return buttonView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="#FF7CB8"
    android:id="@+id/linear" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="#CA2C68" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>



<com.example.slidee.PagerContainer
    android:id="@+id/pager_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/linear"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear"
    android:background="#29C5FF" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="234dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#29C5FF" />
</com.example.slidee.PagerContainer>
```

[image: This is the result. But I would determine the size of the button.]

Comment: You can simply add it to view page layout. Can you post the layout for the pages.

Comment: How I do? You could show me with some code? I tried but It give error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewPager expects the contained view to occupy the whole container.
Use some layout to contain a button:

```
LinearLayout lay = new LinearLayout(PagerActivity.this);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
buttonView.setLayoutParams(lp);
lay.addView(buttonView);
container.addView(lay);
```

Answer (score 1):

an other way to do it is to make a new xml file and inflate it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/viewpager_button"
android:background="@drawable/button_states_azul"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in `instantiateItem`

```
LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        View pagerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_layout, null);
Button button = (Button) pagerView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_button);
container.addView(button);
```

Comment: This works but identifying the layout instead of the button: LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) pagerView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_layout);
            container.addView(linear);

Comment: @Pablo Villar your right you could add the layout. i just copped this from one of my projects where i did different things with the button depend on position of the view pager and there i need to add the button to the right position so i add the button not the layout Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the button dynamically and hence by default it does a match_parent for width and height.

Add this line:

```
        buttonView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i do it, create a xml layout you want to inflate. Add all the view you are intending. Then inside your adapter class, inside instantiateItem override do something like this. remember to adjust your xml views to fit parents width and height as you wish.

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_view, container, false);

    // get reference to your button over here if you have one
    Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.enter_button);


    container.addView(view);
    return view;
    }
```